# Custom Query Filter in Elementor doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to use the custom query filter in Elementor, but even the simple Elementor example doesn't work for me. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.
Here is my code in functions:

```
    function query_filter($query){
    $query -> set('post_type', 'ship');
};

    add_filter('elementor/query/my_query', 'query_filter');
```

And I have this name set in Elementor:
[Custom query id Elementor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luWLv.png)

I'm just trying to show all custom post types 'ship' but it doesn't work.
I am not receiving any error in PHP or in JS on the console.

PD: The Query ID is the only one I have so it is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case is usefull for someone: I found the problem: In elementor when I select 'SOURCE' if I set 'current query' it just show the actual page. I need to select any other option in order to be able to user the Custom Query.

Also try with with both:

```
add_filter('elementor/query/my_query', 'query_filter'); 
add_action('elementor/query/my_query', 'query_filter');
```